# Thread を start() と run() で実行するときの違い

Tags: java

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // something
    }
});
```

このような Thread を、`thread.start()` と `thread.run()` で実行するのにはどんな違いがあるのでしょうか。

Comment: `new Thread(new Runnable() {`の部分は`new Thread() {`とも書けますね。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

非同期で実行するには `thread.start()` を使います。これにより、別スレッドが立った上で、その別スレッド上で `run()` が呼び出されます。
一方、 `thread.run()` は同期で実行されてしまいます。
`run()` を呼ぶと、Runnable を実装したクラスの `run()` メソッドが実行されてしまうため、同期処理になります。